# ISNULL() doesn't return a value when no record returned

Tags: sql, t-sql

In the case where no record matches ICAO='YXTO'

```
SELECT 1, ISNULL((SELECT ID FROM Location WHERE ICAO='YXTO'),2)
```

Returns 1,2

Whereas

```
SELECT 1, (SELECT ISNULL(ID,2) FROM Location WHERE ICAO='YXTO')
```

Returns 1, NULL

What's happening? Does ISNULL not return a value when there is no record to act on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct.

In the first case, the subquery is a scalar subquery.  When there is no match, the result is `NULL`.  This is passed as an argument to `ISNULL()`, so the `2` is returned.

In the second case, the subquery is also a scalar subquery.  When there is no match, it also returns `NULL` -- there is no row returned so the `ISNULL()` never gets called.  Nothing catches the `NULL`, so hence `NULL` is returned.